# Load big file into REST api, but avoid it being a global variable

Tags: python, rest, flask, global-variables

I have multiple functions in my API, which need to refer to a var which loads a big file. The pattern I have so far is with multiple functions in a file and loading that big file in a global variable.

```
global var

function(var) {}
function(var) {}
function(var) {}
```

I would like to get rid of the global variable. Because the global variable can cause conflicts against multiple requests. What are my options ?

Also, if I do the loading in a class, wouldn't I have to instantiate it as a global variable or if I instantiate it in every function, wouldn't it consume too much memory ? (like the size of that file for each instance?)

Thanks !!

Comment: I'm guessing that the big file contents aren't meant to be read-only, since you mention it causing conflicts across requests. Are changes to the global variable (as it is at the moment, at least) meant to be saved for future requests? How big is the data?

Comment: @SimonFraser The file is a machine learning model, so the incoming data would interact with this file and use caffe framework for interaction, which takes some processing time and returns a value. So the file doesn't take changes to be saved but takes time to output the result. The file would be around 400mb.